# Failed to connect to localhost port 1080: Connection refused

Tags: php, curl, connection-refused

Hi am using following code:

```
function curl_get($url){        
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    } 
    $ch = curl_init();   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo curl_error($ch);
    return $response;
}
echo  curl_get('http://gr8logics.com/'); die;
```

This code is working on other local system using localhost but not on my system. My curl is already enabled. I believe it happen after my windows update, but I don't know what changes have been done. I am using xampp 7.0. Please help!!!!

Comment: Do you see any error? If yes, mention it.

Comment: When you enter in browser `http://localhost:1080` is it working fine?

Comment: Yes curl_error($ch); give Failed to connect to localhost port 1080: Connection refused
No any other error even after enable error reporting.

Comment: Enable `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` to get more clues, and check if you perhaps have a proxy environment variable set?

Comment: http://localhost:1080  is not working fine:

This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);  does not provide any info.

Comment: At first, check if service running, use: netstat -pnlt | grep '1080'. Then see which interface it's bound to. Edit config of service (vi /etc/<your service>), save and restart

Comment: 1080 is not listed here (vi /etc/<your service>

Comment: @Justinas please tell me if u have any solution..thanks

Comment: @SanjayGupta So if you don't have localhost mapped to 1080 port, then no wonder it's not working. Maybe try localhost without port (actually it's default 80 port)

Comment: @Justinas I do so but still giving same error..Thanks